# Как посмотреть текущие SSH подключения?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ssh

Хотелось бы с указанием IP. Или это невозможно?

Comment: Есть простая команда которая нужна именно тебе - who

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы посмотреть установленные ssh соединения, [ss(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html):

```
$ ss -o state established '( dport = :ssh or sport = :ssh )'
```

Чтобы посмотреть, кто залогинен, с какого ip и какую команду выполняют, [w(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/w.1.html):

```
$ w
```

Comment: Удивительно сколько дублирующих инструментов в linux.

Comment: @Hipster man говорит netstat устарела. ss  (Socket Statistics) это замена. Другие утилиты для других задач. К примеру, lsof об открытых файлах (менее специализированная — сокеты это всего один из типов файлов). w и who о пользователях. То есть если вам нужна подробная информация о сокетах, то ss это естественный выбор.

Answer (score 4):

```
netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'
```

Вывод примерно такой будет:

```
suvitruf@eu-west-test-services:~$ netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'
tcp        0     64 10.0.0.1:22           111.111.11.111:53722    ESTABLISHED 23359/sshd: suvitru
```

`111.111.11.111` - ip подключившегося.

Comment: круто спасибо!!

Comment: @Hipster рад помочь ^_^

Answer (score 3):

например:

```
$ sudo lsof -n -a -itcp -stcp:established -c sshd
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    9858  root    3u  IPv4 32276937      0t0  TCP 10.0.0.1:ssh->10.0.0.2:59964 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    9864 alice    3u  IPv4 32276937      0t0  TCP 10.0.0.1:ssh->10.0.0.2:59964 (ESTABLISHED)
```

хотя показаны две строки, но, фактически, это одно соединение к локальному компьютеру (`10.0.0.1`, порт 22 (`ssh`)) с удалённого (`10.0.0.2`, порт 59964). просто процесс *sshd*, выполняющийся от имени *root*, создал дочерний процесс, но уже от имени *alice*.

---

пояснения (см. `$ man lsof`):

- `-n` — не пытаться преобразовывать ip-адреса в доменные имена (может значительно ускорить работу)
- `-a` — применить логическую операцию «и» («and»)
- `-itcp` — показать tcp-сокеты
- `-stcp:established` — показать tcp-сокеты, находящиеся в состоянии «established»
- `-c sshd` — показать процессы, запущенные из бинарных файлов, имена которых начинаются строкой `sshd`

---

почему два фильтры `-itcp` и `-c sshd` вместо одного `-itcp:22`?

потому что в этом случае в вывод попадут и процессы *ssh*, запущенные локально и подключившиеся к 22-ым портам каких-нибудь машин. к тому же, в случае, если ваш *sshd* слушает и/или порт(ы), отличный(е) от 22-го, то такие соединения просто не попадут в вывод.

Answer (score 0):

Есть простая команда которая нужна именно тебе

```
who
```