# Как вывести количество ожидающих приёма соединений?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian

```
$ netstat -Lan // не работает

Current listen queue sizes (qlen/incqlen/maxqlen)
Listen         Local Address         
0/0/128        *.12345            
10/0/128        *.80       
0/0/128        *.8080
```

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/#optimize

Comment: Разве в приведенном вами примере вывода `10/0/128` число 10 это не то о чем вы спрашиваете? (количество пришедших, но еще не установленных (т.е. accept() для них не вызывался) соединений)

Comment: @avp Пример то я понимаю, только я не знаю какой командой получить такой вывод.

Comment: @Hipster  по ссылке в вашем вопросе, пример проводится на машине с одной из BSD системой, где есть поддержка опции -L, наверняка вы пробуете (надо бы описать, где пробуете в вопросе) на одной из GNU/Linux системе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мои эксперименты показали, что надо вызывать
`ss -la | grep` *`your-port`* `| grep LISTEN`

Тогда число в поле `Recv-Q` показывает количество полученных соединений для которых сервер еще не сделал вызов `accept()`.

Кстати, в поле `Send-Q` этого сокета показана максимальная длина очереди ожидающих приема (pending) соединений. Другими словами, это то число, которое мы передаем вторым аргументом в `listen()`.

Answer (score 1):

вероятно, подразумеваются *tcp*-соединения, находящиеся [в состоянии *listen*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B0_TCP)

получить их список можно, например, программой *lsof* (приведён пример вывода):

```
$ sudo lsof -n -itcp -stcp:listen
COMMAND     PID         USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd        725         root    3u  IPv4 104540750      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd        725         root    4u  IPv6 104540752      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
dnsmasq    1969       nobody    6u  IPv4     22700      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.1:domain (LISTEN)
adb        8882         user    6u  IPv4  31077050      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5037 (LISTEN)
qemu-syst 10337 libvirt-qemu   17u  IPv4  70173191      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5900 (LISTEN)
exim4     10685  Debian-exim    3u  IPv4  27902129      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:smtp (LISTEN)
exim4     10685  Debian-exim    4u  IPv6  27902130      0t0  TCP [::1]:smtp (LISTEN)
cupsd     17961         root    9u  IPv6 111981277      0t0  TCP [::1]:ipp (LISTEN)
cupsd     17961         root   10u  IPv4 111981278      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:ipp (LISTEN)
```

чтобы отобрать только сокеты, созданные процессом, запущенном из файла с именем, начинающимся, например, с символов `exim`, надо добавить опцию `-c имя` и опцию `-a` (логическое «и» по отношению к опциям):

```
$ sudo lsof -n -itcp -stcp:listen -c exim -a
COMMAND   PID        USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
exim4   10685 Debian-exim    3u  IPv4 27902129      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:smtp (LISTEN)
exim4   10685 Debian-exim    4u  IPv6 27902130      0t0  TCP [::1]:smtp (LISTEN)
```

точное совпадение с именем можно указать с помощью регулярного выражения (см. `$ man lsof`):

```
$ sudo lsof -n -itcp -stcp:listen -c '/^exim4$/' -a
...
```

---

чтобы подсчитать количество строк, можно воспользоваться программой *wc* с опцией `-l`, предварительно удалив первую строку, например, программой *tail* с опцией `-n +2`:

```
$ sudo lsof -n -itcp -stcp:listen -c exim -a | tail -n +2 | wc -l
2
```

---

практически аналогичный вопрос: [Как посмотреть текущие SSH подключения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/753910/178576)

Answer (score 0):

Пакет **iprout2** является предпочтительным на современных GNU/Linux

```
~# ss -la

-a, --all
Display all sockets. 
-l, --listening
Display listening sockets.
```

---

UPD

Опция **-L** у netstat присуствует только в *BSD Unix'ax в версиях для *Linux этой опции нет. Альтернатива этому Recv-Q и Send-Q

> Recv-Q
>
> Установленное: количество байт не скопированное пользовательской программой, подключенной к данному сокету.
>
> Ожидаемое: С версии ядра 2.6.18 эта колонка содержит значения синхронизации (syn backlog)
>
> Send-Q
>
> Установленное: количество байт НЕ принятых удаленной машиной.
>
> Ожидаемое: с версии ядрка 2.6.18 эта колонка  содержит максимальный размер синхронизации (syn backlog)
>
> Если значения равны 0 это значит, что ваше приложение на обоих конца
>   соединения и сети между ними работает нормально (OK).
>
> Фактические мгновенные значения могут отличатся от 0, но вы не сможете
>   их отследить.
>
> Перевод ->
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466744/use-of-recv-q-and-send-q

**Ссылки**

- https://github.com/Hellseher/cix/blob/master/spices/cix-iproute2.org
- http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2-toc.html
- https://serverfault.com/questions/432022/linux-netstat-listeting-queue-length
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466744/use-of-recv-q-and-send-q
- http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html

Comment: По-моему `ss` не выводит такой информации. Я вижу только колонки: Netid  State, Recv-Q, Send-Q, Local Address:Port, Peer Address:Port.

Comment: @Hipster обновил ответ

Comment: Нет, насколько я понимаю колонки `Recv-Q` и `Send-Q` это не количество соединений во входящей и исходящей очереди, а количество байт. В документации NGINX они то количество соединений считали.

Comment: @Hipster Там опечатка в примере (по вашей ссылке) у программы netstat нет опции **-L** есть опция **-l, listnening** (ее нет в  Ubuntu 12,16 и Fedora 27)   значит они пытались показать количество "слушающих" подлючений для  Nginx, что и выводять команды **ss -la**, **netstat -lan**

Comment: Наверно опечатка, но всё равно как очереди то посмотреть? Или как их перевести из байтов в штуки?

Comment: @Hipster расширил ответ

Comment: С `Send-Q` понятно откуда берётся количество байт (сервер знает размер своего ответа), а откуда клиент знает какого размера ответ он хочет получить (`Recv-Q`)? Я что то не понимаю.